# How can I plot the summation of several variables?

Tags: matlab, plot, sum, visualization, symbolic-math

I am trying to visualize an equation, `a*sin(n*pi*x*t)`, where:

- `a` is a constant
- `n` is a shape mode (1,2,...)
- `t` is time
- `x` is displacement

This is my code:

```
syms n t x

a=1

S=symsum(a*sin(n*pi*x*t),n,1,10)

plot(t,S)
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Error using plot
A numeric or double convertible argument is expected

Error in Untitled (line 8)
plot(t,subs(S,x,t))
```

What can I do?

Comment: You need to explain better. Your question is really not clear in what you want or what your variables are. A [mcve] is important for other people compare and debug.

Comment: You can not plot a symbolic equation, that is obvious. It has no numeric values, right?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use symbolic variables for this, here's an example of how to do this:

```
%% Definitions:
a = cat(3,1,-1,3);  % size(a) == [1,1,3]
n = cat(4,1,2,3,4); % size(a) == [1,1,1,4]
%% Grid for x,t
x_lims = [-2  2]; x_resolution = 50; X = linspace(x_lims(1),x_lims(2),x_resolution);
t_lims = [ 0 20]; t_resolution = 20; T = linspace(t_lims(1),t_lims(2),t_resolution);
[XX,TT] = meshgrid(X,T);
ZZ = a .* sin(pi * n .* XX .* TT); % size(ZZ) == [200,100,3,4]; Also, see note at the end
%% Plot
nA = numel(a); nN = numel(n);
figure(); subplot(nA, nN, 1);
for indA = 1:nA
  for indN = 1:nN
    subplot(nA, nN, (indA-1)*nN + indN);
    surf(XX,TT,ZZ(:,:,indA,indN),'EdgeColor','none');
    view([90,90]);
  end
end
```

Which yields:

[image: Example]

Where in each plot `t` is on the horizontal axis and `x` is on the vertical, the different `a` values are the rows of the subplot, and different `n` values are the columns.

Note that I used implicit expansion in my code; if you have an old MATLAB version you'll have to use `bsxfun`.

Comment: Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in exam29 (line 16)
ZZ = a .* sin(pi * n .* XX .* TT);

Comment: @Hossein as my note said, you must be using a pretty old MATLAB version. Where you see `.*` it needs to be changed to `bsxfun(@times,operand1,operand2)`, so basically something like  `bsxfun(@times,a,sin(pi * bsxfun(@times,n,....) )`. Please leave me another comment if you can't fix this on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plot` for drawing symbolic variables.

A simple solution for this problem is using `ezplot` instead `plot`.